# Delete file by date in its name

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a list of files that looks like this:

```
...
live-2014-04-28.tar.bz2
live-2014-04-29.tar.bz2
live-2014-04-30.tar.bz2
live-2014-05-01.tar.bz2
live-2014-05-01.tar.bz2
live-2014-05-02.tar.bz2
...
```

... and trying to delete files older then a week with bash script:

```
c=0
for i in `echo "ls /filebackup/daily" | sftp somepath.your-backup.de`
do
        c=`expr $c + 1`
        [ $c -le 3 ] && continue
        d=`echo $i | sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+).*/\1/'`
        d=`date -d $d +'%s'`
        echo $c
        if [ `expr $dc - 691200` -ge $d ]
        then
                echo 'here file will be deleted'
        fi
done
```

I can't get inside `echo 'here file will be deleted'`, was trying to debug – not quite sure what `$dc` part does (I'm quite with coding in bash).

I'm using this code from [this article](https://abendstille.at/blog/?p=150) (see The File-Backup-Script part), and trying to understand why it doesn't work on my side.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Oh, there are far too many of such questions already.  Please attempt to search a bit.

Comment: I'm almost certain the author of that post put a `d=` where they meant `dc=` on the second `d=` line, but I'm in no position at present to check/explain better

Comment: @devnull I'm sorry if there is an answer for this, but I'm sitting on this problem for an hour, and can't find any solution. It's hard to search something when you don't know what to search.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current and store in a variable
currDate=$(date +'%Y%m%d')  

# set this shell option to prevent literal match when no files exists
shopt -s nullglob

# Iterate over your directory
for file in *.bz2; do
    f=${file%%.*}                        # Strip the trailing extensions => live-2014-04-28
    f=${f#*-}                            # Strip the leading hyphen => 2014-04-28
    f=${f//-/}                           # Substitute all hyphens in date => 20140428
    if (( f <= (currDate - 7) )); then   # If the date is less than week old
        echo rm $file ...                # delete it
    fi
done
```

I have put `echo` before `rm` command so that you can test the output. If you are satisfied with the result then you can remove the `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

> rying to delete files older then a week with bash script.

What if you ignore the names of the files and just use the timestamp?

```
$ find . -name "live-*.tar.bz2" -mtime +7 -delete
```

It's not exactly what you want, but it's simple.